# How do I get xinputrc to work for login screen?

Tags: linux-mint, xinput, display-manager

I have the following lines in /etc/X11/xinit/xinputrc to tame my mouse sensitivity:

```
xinput --set-prop 9 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 4.5
xinput --set-prop 9 "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 1
xinput --set-prop 9 "Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration" 1.5
```

These work great, the mouse behaves as I want.

However, these commands only get run after a user logs in - on the login screen the mouse has the default sensitivities and is almost unusable.

How do I get xinput commands to run that effect the login screen?

Running LinuxMint 17.1, standard display manager (mdm).

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

greeter-setup-script=/my/path/to/script

with the script of course being your script that runs xinput.